# convert javascript number to css value -- maximum number of trailing decimals

Tags: javascript, css

I am about to have some fun with the css transform matrix and javascript. At the moment everything is cool, except when a number becomes something like 0.000034e3344 after the to string conversion. Than the transform does not work.
So I know that there is the

```
Number.toFixed()
```

method which actually solves the problem, but i ask myself how many trailing decimals make sense. So what is the highest value i can pass to the toFixed() method to get the most precise results?

EDIT:::

the exact number output was:

9.685539407532573e-20

Comment: `0.000034e3344` is a HUGE number (`3.4 * 10^3339`). Or was the `e` a typo?

Comment: may be this is 0.00000-e333, i have not copied the number via copy and paste. this just to base e, isn't it? it was exactly: 9.685539407532573e-20 <- copy & paste

Comment: No, it's base 10. e doesn't mean euler, but exponent in here.

Comment: excuse me for my lacks of maths, but in this case I think this is not the core of the problem. The question is how many trailing digits make sense for css.

Comment: Okay, so `9.685539407532573e-20` is `0.00000000000000000009685539407532573` which is a *tiny* number. I think you're seeing the transform "not work" simply because the value you're setting is basically zero.

Comment: and this is the question. Maybe I could not clearify this. If I use toFixed( 20 ), what is the maximum Value i found out a few minutes ago, it works fine. So i think it is the e, that brakes the transformation, just because it results in an non valid css-value. But what i am interesset in is: with how much precission can css deal with and how much it uses rounded values internally.

Comment: Too unclear from the formulation what it is you want for the question to be given any better treatment.